# Embed quicktime player in webpage to play rtsp live stream in android

Tags: android, quicktime

I have the following code to play rtsp stream in quicktime player in the webpage itself without opening external video player.

```
<OBJECT classid='clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B' width="320" height="240" codebase='http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab'>
        <param name='src' value="rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov">
        <param name='autoplay' value="true">
        <param name='controller' value="false">
        <param name='loop' value="false">
        <EMBED src="rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov" width="320" height="240" autoplay="true"
        controller="true" loop="false" bgcolor="#000000" pluginspage='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/'>
        </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

This plays well in desktop but not in android devices. I only see a weird icon and player is not setup.

Comment: What makes you think apple provides a quicktime plugin for android devices?  On Android, you choices are likely the built in player, and on later devices perhaps, flash and on the latest html5.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I certainly dont know if apple provides a quicktime plugin for android devices but i definitely want some player to embed in the webpage itself without opening the built in player. `rtsp` stream cannot be played in flash player or html5 player

Comment: I have search everywhere but this problem seems unsolved as far as I can see. Will follow further responses with interest.

Answer (score 1):

Android devices may have their own native player.  As such you just need to provide a link to the video which will automatically open and play the video in the native player.

Comment: My initial question is not to open the native player but embed any player in the webpage to handle `rtsp` stream